# How to use pytorch multiprocessing to train models separately

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing

I am looking at the torch.multiprocessing module and trying to use it speed up my code. I just want to repeatedly train several neural networks with the same dataset. So I don't want to share any training process parameters among them except the initial dataset. I am wondering will torch.multiprocessing suits for this case? I saw many examples but they are all about distributed learning.

A quick code example is appreciated!

Comment: by "repeatedly", you mean one trial after the other, or do you want to run them simultaneously?

Comment: I mean to run them simultaneously. But each one does not interface with another one. Something like 'repeatedly' when not using multiprocessing.

Comment: Why not just run the same code in several terminal instead?